# How to announce failure when inside a catch-all statement?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

Unfortunately, some of the code base I have to work with and unable to change right now looks something like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        do_stuff()
    except:
        time.sleep(0.005)
```

Which means, any exceptions gets caught, silently.

How can I bypass this horror?

I am using the simplest test code, and I can't easily know when it fails.

I can't raise anything, and I can't use exit()

What is the standard thing to do in this case?

Comment: It’s bad practice to use a bare `except`. Use `except Exception` at the least. Then when you need to debug, put a bare `raise` in the `except` clause to re-raise the exception which was caught. If you just need to print the error message, use `except Exception as e: print(e)`

Comment: It sounds like you want to call `do_stuff()` directly from your test code.